# How to loop through HTML to get data in order with scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

For example I have a HTML like this:

```html
<div id="des">
    <p>One</p>
    <p>Second</p>
    <img src="firstimage" alt="">
    <p>Third</p>
    <img src="secondimage" alt="">
    <p>Fourth</p>
</div>
```

I can use this single line to get all p texts as:

```py
des = response.css("#des p::text").getall()
```

or images as same.

However what I want is like I will have an array of the data (text for p and src for img) as ordered in the HTML page for example:

```
["one", "second", "firstimage", "third", "secondimage", "fourth"]
```

I know there is Items which may help me but couldn't figure how to achieve this. Is there a way that I can loop through in `div id="des"` and get data in ordered way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize two selectors in one query, which will extract in order of occurance.

```
response.css("#des p::text, #des img::attr(src)").extract()
#['One', 'Second', 'firstimage', 'Third', 'secondimage', 'Fourth']
```